# why we create polls/urls.py module in app directory even we can do the whole thing in project's mysite/urls.py?

Tags: django

Code below in my polls/urls.py

from django.urls import path
from . import views

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index),   # name='whatever_name'

path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),

path('<int:question_id>/results', views.results, name='result'),

path('<int:question_id>/vote', views.vote, name= 'vote'),
```

]

then i delete the file and add everything in mysite/urls.py which is the root urls module, and it was working fine

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from polls import views

urlpatterns = [
path('polls/', views.index, name='index'),
path('polls/<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
path('polls/<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='result'),
path('polls/<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name= 'vote'),
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

]

Comment: Has to be properly indented to read.

Answer (score 3):

Yes putting URLs inside the root `urls.py` works perfectly fine. For simple projects with one app you can put URLs in the same file i.e the project level `urls.py` file but for big projects with multiple apps it's very recommended that you create self contained and separate apps (a decoupled architecture). This way you can better manage the project complexity, you can easily swap apps, and most importantly you can re-use your apps very easily across other projects since the app contains all its functionality (including urls) and even better you can share your apps as packages so other developer can use them.